# addClass doesn't work (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in jQuery and I need some help. I have a little problem with addClass

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    Container 1
    <div class="second hide">
        Some text 1
        <div class="close">close</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    Container 2
    <div class="second hide">
        Some text 2
        <div class="close">close 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery

```
$("div.first").click(function() {
    $("div.first").find("div.second").addClass('hide');
    $(this).find("div.second").removeClass('hide');
});

$("div.close").click(function() {   
    $("div.close").parent().addClass('hide');
    $(this).parent().addClass('hide');
});
```

What I need.

1. click container 1.1 -> show container 1.2
2. click container 2.1 -> show container 2.2, hide container 1.2
3. click container 1.1 -> show container 1.2, hide container 2.2

and all I listed above works.

Now I need to hide all containers x.2 when "close" is clicked. I think there is a conflict, but I don't know where.

here is http://jsfiddle.net/E69AN/2/

Comment: for show/hide use jquery method instead $(selector).show() && $(selector).hide()  instead ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the click event on the `close` button, otherwise you are clicking close, and then immediately re-opening the div. Try this:

```
$("div.first").click(function() {
    $("div.second").addClass('hide');
    $(this).find("div.second").removeClass('hide');
});

$("div.close").click(function(e) {   
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.second').addClass('hide');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E69AN/4/)

Answer (score 2):

when you click on the `.close` div, this will lead to call 2 click functions, because it is inside the `div.first`.

1. First it execute `$("div.close").click(fu....`, which will lead to hide the `div.first`
2. Immediatly it execute `$("div.first").click(fu....`, which will lead to show the `div.first`

you can prevent this behaviour by `e.stopPropagation();`:

```
 $("div.first").click(function() {
    $(".second").hide();
    $(this).find(".second").show();
});

$("div.close").click(function(e) {    
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E69AN/6/)